# stored procedure with custom parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create a stored procedure to summarize counts in a view I created, but I need to use a custom parameter because I want to filter on start and end dates (two of my parameters) and those are supposed to rely on user input.

For example, I want to have something like this except I want the @Name to be a value that is set by another person, not set in the procedure itself.  What would be the best way to go about this?

```
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(20)
SET @Name='User1'
SELECT
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN Name=@Name THEN Total*-1
            ELSE Total
        END
    ) [Total Adj]
    ,Date
FROM Table
GROUP BY Date
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Are you saying that the start and end dates are declared by one user and the name by another?

Comment: Oh disregard the start/end date part.  I'm looking at solely names in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a SP:

```
CREATE PROC some_proc @Name VARCHAR(20)
SELECT
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN Name=@Name THEN Total*-1
            ELSE Total
        END
    ) [Total Adj]
    ,Date
FROM Table
GROUP BY Date
```

And use it:

```
some_proc 'User1'
```

Comment: What if I have multiple parameters (say I throw in a date parameter too)?  Then would I call it as some_proc 'User1' 'Date1'?

Comment: Sure: CREATE PROC some_proc 'at'Name VARCHAR(20) , 'at'Date1 DATE.  to call it just add date after a comma. GL!

Comment: Where would you type some_proc 'User1' when you're implementing the procedure?  I didn't know you could just type it into the query window in MS SQL Server for example and it'd run.  Cool!

Comment: Alright--but where would you type some_proc 'User1' when you're implementing the procedure?

Answer (score 0):

You can call you so in following manner:

```
Exec spname 'name','param1','param2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a table function. Basically the same as a procedure, but can be used similar to a view. Also, as a function is returning something, I prefer to use a function to return data. A procedure does something. But, this is only my personal opinion.

```
create function dbo.some_func(@Name Varchar(30))
returns table
as
begin
  return(
    SELECT
      SUM(CASE WHEN Name=@Name THEN Total*-1 ELSE Total END) [Total Adj]
         ,Date
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY Date
)
end
```

Comment: Using a function instead of a stored proc introduces limitations.  For example, you can call one stored procedure from another, but you can't call one from a function.

Comment: @DanBracuk: Thank you very much for this comment. I never ran into this problem yet but it is interesting to know. However, in this case (inline table functions) these limitations do not apply. It is a nice 'parametrized view'.